# Обособление оборота с предлогом "ради"

Tags: пунктуация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой случай "спорный" или "бесспорный", авторский?

> По сюжету моя героиня, ради подвенечного убора к свадьбе со своим
>   заморским принцем, истребляет род прекрасных птиц, а в финале
>   спектакля сама обращается в белую цаплю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *По сюжету моя героиня, ради подвенечного убора к свадьбе со своим заморским принцем, истребляет род прекрасных птиц, а в финале
>   спектакля сама обращается в белую цаплю.*

Запятые, выделяющие в этом предложении оборот *"ради подвенечного убора к свадьбе со своим заморским принцем"*, **обязательны.**

При невыделении этого оборота возможно двоякое прочтение: то ли героиня одна  истребляет *род прекрасных птиц*, то ли и заморский принц принимает участие в этом истреблении.

Comment: Потому что оборот вклинен между подлежащим и сказуемым? Ога! Прочла пояснение, спасибо!